# c# how to filter stimulsoft report programatically?

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

I am working on a c# project. I used stimulsoft to create and show report in my project.
I design my report in stimulsoft software and save my report file in ...\bin\debug\reports path.

this is my report design :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ5d3.png)

this report shows system users.

Now, i want to filter my report in c#. how can i send formul to filter my report result?

this is my code to show report:

```
    StiReport report = new StiReport();
        report.Load(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\reports\\userinfo.mrt");
        report.Show();
```

Comment: Your question lacks of some important informations. First what version of Stimulsoft are you using? (WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, or...) Second, what kind of source are you using for your data? (DataSource, BusinessObjects, or...)

Comment: @Steve i used WinForms and EntityFramework

Comment: No, I am asking about the DataSource/BusinessObject choice done inside the Report Designer to build the Dictionary used to prepare the report fields.

Comment: However, if you look at their FAQ file for NET programmers you will find easily the lines about passing a parameter to an sql query used to build a datasource.

Comment: @Steve excuse me for my reply, i used Data Source to connect database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is partially taken from their file `Stimulsoft_NET_FAQ.pdf`

First you create a parameter in the query used to extract data from the datasource

```
SELECT * from Users WHERE userID  =  @userID
```

then you pass this parameter before calling Show

```
StiReport report = new StiReport();
report.Load(.... your file....));
report.Dictionary.Databases.Clear();
StiSqlDatabase db = new StiSqlDatabase("the_name_of_datasource", "the connection string");
report.Dictionary.Databases.Add(db);
report.CacheAllData = true;
report.Dictionary.Synchronize();
report.Compile();
// Finally set the parameter
report["@userID"] = 1; // <= value to search for....
report.Show(true);
```

This example is for an Sql Server Database backend. If you have a different database engine then please use one of the various `StiXXXXXXDatabase` classes available